# How do I make this Red Mark on Augmented Reality Marker using Marker Based Vuforia

Tags: augmented-reality, vuforia

[How to create a Red Mark on Augmented Reality Marker using Marker Based Vuforia and when the red mark is touched, a 3d object that matches the red mark that is selected will appear.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuGgd.jpg)

I have used various methods and the video maker said he used a marker-based system, and here I am confused about what to do.

Answer (score 0):

This type of experience could be created with Vuforia Engine, but it would use "Virtual Buttons" which is deprecated in the newest version. I'd recommend to look into either Vuforia Engine + ARFoundation, or solely ARFoundation, to use Image Tracking + Hand Detection.